# Why is printing out with format throwing NoneType error?

Tags: python, error-handling

```
account_balance = {'a': '122.8', 'b': '14.1', 'c': '31.44', 'd': '15.15', 'e': '23.07'}
total = 0.00
for key in account_balance:
    total += float(account_balance[key])
```

Then this:

```
print("TOTAL: {0}").format(str(total))
```

throws an error of:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'format'

... why?

Comment: You’re calling `.format()` on `print()`, instead of on the string. I would suggest using f-strings.

Comment: Final answer is:
print("TOTAL: {0}".format(str(total)))
vs.
print("TOTAL: {0}").format(str(total))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```
print("TOTAL: {0}".format(str(total)))
```

Your original code is trying to call the `.format()` method to the `print` function's return value. Since that is always `None`, you get an `AttributeError`.

If you're using Python `>=3.6`, I would suggest you use [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) for this. They are wonderful to use and will make string formatting a joy:

```
print(f"TOTAL: {total}")
```

---

Also this code:

```
account_balance = {'a': '122.8', 'b': '14.1', 'c': '31.44', 'd': '15.15', 'e': '23.07'}
total = 0.00
for key in account_balance:
    total += float(account_balance[key])
```

Can be simplified and made more efficient by using `sum` with a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/):

```
total = sum(float(value) for value in account_balance.values())
```

Or alternatively using `sum` and `map`:

```
total = sum(map(float, account_balance.values()))
```

---

So all together to make your code nice and easy to read:

```
account_balance = {'a': '122.8', 'b': '14.1', 'c': '31.44', 'd': '15.15', 'e': '23.07'}
total = sum(float(value) for value in account_balance.values())
print(f"TOTAL: {total}")
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> TOTAL: 206.56
> ```

Comment: Why not `account_balance.values()` though?

Comment: @SayandipDutta Yeah just realised that also myself, fixed :)

Answer (score -2):

You may want to try this:
`account_balance = {'a': '122.8', 'b': '14.1', 'c': '31.44', 'd': '15.15', 'e': '23.07'}
total = 0.00
for key in account_balance:
    total += float(account_balance[key])`

`print(total)`
`206.56`